# Referring to a character by a trait rather than name/title/pronoun

Tags: single-word-requests, literary-techniques

This is really driving me insane. What is it called when instead of referring to a character by their name, title, or pronoun you use a short description. For example, "the cruel man spoke", "the junkie laughed", "the older sister followed". They aren't really kennings or epithets, but it's similar.

Answer (score 2):

In Stylistics this is termed ***Periphrasis***:

Use of a longer phrasing in place of a possible shorter form of expression.

(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/periphrasis)